# Backbone.js - Update specific attribute on Model does not want to fire "change" event

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js

In the following code,

```
this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:voteCount', this.changeVoteCount);
this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.renderTemplate);
```

If "`voteCount`" attribute updated, I want to trigger "`this.changeVoteCount`" method but **not** trigger "`this.renderTemplate`".

I already googling about 2 hours and couldn't find solution. How can I do for this requirement?

#### Update

(just the explanation for why I choose @try-catch-finally answer)

For people who also meet this problem, I want to clear out the confusion which answer should be chosen as their solution.

I will describe some details to explain why I choose this answer. The following is my model structure:

```
{
   'name': 'some string',
   'location': 'some string',
   'link': 'some string',
   'voteCount': 0    }
```

Otherwise '`voteCount`' attribute updated, I want to trigger "change" event binded method (in my case, `this.renderTemplate`).

So I tried the first approach,

```
this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:name change:location change:link', this.renderTemplate);
```

In this approach, if I update '`location`' and '`name`' at once in one place, then the `this.renderTemplate` method will trigger two times. I want `this.renderTemplate` method trigger just one time whenever '`location`', '`name`' or '`link`' attributes updated separately or together at the same time.

So finally, I tried the following approach and succeed.

```
this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', function(model) {
            if (_.isEmpty(_.intersection(_.keys(model.changed), ["voteCount"]))) {
                this.renderTemplate.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        });
```

Comment: @Remco Haszing, your edit is wrong. The TOs intentions was not to handle the event for a specific attribute. Your title reads Backbone isn't doing this while the TO is expecting it.

Comment: Added note about debounce in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beside listing all attributes you want to listen for their change mentioned by @antejan, you could do this programatically too.

This way you'd examine the model's `changed` attribute which contains all attributes that have been changed.

```
this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', function(model) {
     if (!_.contains(_.keys(model.changed), "voteCount") {
          this.renderTemplate.apply(this, arguments);
     }
});
```

When blacklisting multiple keys you could also do:

```
if (_.isEmpty(_.intersection(_.keys(model.changed), ["attr1", "attr2", ...])) { ...
```

As long as your model does only have a few attributes I'd prefer @antejans way of listing all attributes explicitly since its more clear whats going on:

```
this.listenTo(this.model, "change:attr1 change:attr2 ...", this.renderTemplate);
```

Note that there might be a performance penalty when listing multiple `change:attr` events since Backbone will call the listeners in a `for`-loop. See the [annotated Backbone source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-73) of `set()`:

```
  ...

  if (!silent) {
    if (changes.length) this._pending = options;
    for (var i = 0, l = changes.length; i < l; i++) {
      this.trigger('change:' + changes[i], this, current[changes[i]], options);
    }
  }

  // You might be wondering why there's a `while` loop here. Changes can
  // be recursively nested within `"change"` events.
  if (changing) return this;
  if (!silent) {
    while (this._pending) {
      options = this._pending;
      this._pending = false;
      this.trigger('change', this, options);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want render on every parameter change, you can specify which of them should trigger render.

```
this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:param1 change:param2', this.renderTemplate);
```

**Edit:** if you don't want to render multiple times on multiple fields change, you can use underscore's [debounce](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce):

```
this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:param1 change:param2', _.debounce(this.renderTemplate));
```

It will call render only once if it will be called several times in a short time.